# Call jstl variables to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

File name : Test.jsp

I declared a variable under jstl tag

```
<%

String daysToActivate = Someclass.method();

%>
```

I want to call this method in the following javascript fumction

```
//javascript function
function getDays(){



var x= daysToActivate;

alert(x);

}

// this alert message is not displaying.
```

please help

Comment: Try passing the value into the method.

Comment: @duffymo I don't think that is a correct editing, because those has nothing to do with jstl.

Comment: @user3816173 Can you provide the source code from your jst file? You can use http://nopaste.info/ for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't know about Java variables declared in scriptlets and other places. It's because Java code is run and resolved on the server, and JavaScript is run in user's web browser.

To pass variable's value from Java to JavaScript put this script inside JSP page:

```
function getDays(){
    var x = <%= daysToActivate %>;
    alert(x);
}
```

Value of `daysToActivate` will be resolved on the server side, inserted into HTML file as text, and send to the user's web browser. Then on the client's side, from the web browser perspective this function will look like:

```
function getDays(){
    var x = 25;
    alert(x);
}
```

If `daysToActivate` is not an integer, then remember to use `"`:

```
function getDays(){
    var x = "<%= daysToActivate %>";
    alert(x);
}
```

Comment: The value should be JS-escaped to avoid quoting and newline issues.